# using xcodebuild with xcode 6 for ad hoc build crashes unless "clean"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcodebuild

i use xcodebuild for automated builds and i have found that with the new xcode 6, if i don't "clean" between two ad hoc builds, the build crashes when it gets on the device almost immediately. the stack trace looks like this:

```
   Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2e9bbec6 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39156ce2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e9bbe08 +[NSException raise:format:] + 108
3   UIKit                           0x3155c3ec -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 784
4   UIKit                           0x3155dd86 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 134
5   UIKit                           0x314643fe -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 30
6   UIKit                           0x31256bb6 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 478
7   UIKit                           0x311f2c72 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3546
8   UIKit                           0x311f1dd4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
9   UIKit                           0x312563e0 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612
10  GraphicsServices                0x3385fb50 _PurpleEventCallback + 604
11  GraphicsServices                0x3385f73a PurpleEventCallback + 30
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2e986802 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2e98679e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2e984f6a __CFRunLoopRun + 1402
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2e8ef724 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2e8ef506 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
17  UIKit                           0x31255606 -[UIApplication _run] + 758
18  UIKit                           0x3125086c UIApplicationMain + 1132
```

i guess it is prolly better to clean between builds anyway, but i'm not sure if i'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: I'm experiencing more or less the same problem, and it looks as if the xibs aren't being being compiled and copied on the second ad hoc build, but I haven't figured this out yet.

Comment: i just added a "clean" to my build process (which probably should be there anyway) and that seems to work

Comment: I ended up completely gutting and restructuring/modernizing the build commands that were being used -- there were some other deeper problems.